# WhatsApp changed the name of the package? Sudden error with package name

Tags: android, kotlin, whatsapp

I have an integration with wpp in my app, this worked fine for around a year, but I detect that it doesn't work anymore. When the app tries to launch the intent, a NameNotFoundException happens

```
   Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.whatsapp
```

Any idea what's going on?

Edit: I think it's an Android 11 issue, does that make sense?

Comment: They can not change application id . it will be a new app then .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are new changes in android 11 of package visibility. You need to add a new section under you app's  tag: Please go through official documentation [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)

Try this in manifest.xml

```
     <queries>
       
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
       
 </queries>
```

OR this only.

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
</queries>
```